# Resuming flow not working

Tags: visualforce, process-builder, visual-workflow

Creating a flow in the sandbox to capture a survey.

Enabled the ability to Pause the flow and added the component to Home page. All the screens for the flow is complete and when I test, two issues are found.

1. In the last screen I do not find the Finish Button
2. When I resume a Paused flow, after clicking on the last screen, instead of redirecting to the Account page, the flow is restarting again.

Please let me know what is going wrong and what can be done.